# I am using PHPMailer but when I call to the send() function I don't actually receive an email

Tags: php, mysql, class, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer version 5.2

I've edited some of the delicate information for posting sake:

```
try {

class mailer {
    private $email_to;
    private $email_subject;
    private $email_from;
    private $email_headers;
    private $email_html_message;
    private $email_text_message;
    private $mail_object;
    public function __construct($persist = false) {
        $this->email_to = '';
        $this->email_subject = '';
        $this->email_from = '';
        $this->email_html_message = '';
        $this->email_text_message = '';
        $this->email_headers = '';
    }
    // Adds the Email Address to be sent to, to the mailer Object
    public function add_to($email) {
        $this->email_to = $email;
        // $mail->AddAddress ( $email );
    }
    public function add_from($email) {
        $this->email_from = $email;
        // $mail->SetFrom ( $email );
    }
    public function add_subject($subject) {
        // $mail->Subject ( $subject );
    }
    public function add_headers($headers) {
        // $this->email_headers = [$headers[0]] = $headers[1];
        $mail->addCustomHeader ( $headers );
    }
    public function add_html_message($message) {
        $this->email_html_message = $message;
    }
    public function add_text_message($message) {
        $this->email_text_message = $message;
    }
    public function send() {
        $mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x' . md5 ( time () ) . 'x';

        $body = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";

        $body .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $body .= $this->email_text_message;
        $body .= "\n\n";

        $body .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $body .= $this->email_html_message;
        $body .= "\n\n";

        $body .= "--$mime_boundary--\n";

        $headers ["Reply-To"] = $this->email_from;
        $headers ["From"] = "Law Space Match <service@lawspacematch.com>";
        $headers ["IME-Version"] = '1.0';
        $headers ["Content-Type"] = 'multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $mime_boundary . '"';
        $headers ["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = '7bit"';
        $headers ["Return-path"] = "mailer@lawspacematch.com";
        $headers ['Subject'] = $this->email_subject;
        $headers ["X-Sender-IP"] = $_SERVER ['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $headers ["Date"] = date ( 'n/d/Y g:i A' );
        $headers ["To"] = $this->email_to;

        $mail = new PHPMailer ();
        $mail->IsSMTP ();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->Username = "user@GMailSMTPdomain.com";
        $mail->Password = "*********";
        $mail->SetFrom( "sameTest@notGmailDomain.com", "John Doe" );
        $mail->AddAddress( "sameTest@notGmailDomain.com", "John Doe" );
        $mail->Subject = "test";
        $mail->MsgHTML = $body; // or MsgBody?
        $mail->Send ();
        // return $this->mail_object->send ( $this->email_to, $headers, $body );
    }
  }
} catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {
echo $e->errorMessage ();
} catch ( Throwable $e ) {
echo $e->getMessage ();
}
```

I've checked the credentials for the SMTP through a different source and it is in working condition. Yet this won't actually send to me.
Yes, I know there is a lot of junk code that I'm not using. This is because I'm transferring an old mailing system over to PHPMailer so once it's in working condition I will clean it up.
-This was edited for a new problem that I'm now having-

Comment: You're referencing `$mail` inside the class but it's not available there.

Comment: Please read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$mail` does not exist within your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$mail` variable doesn't exist in the scope of the `send()` method of the `mailer` class, you may want instantiate the `PHPMailer` object in the constructor, like in the following example:

```
class mailer {
    [...]
    private $mail;

    public function __construct($persist = false) {
        [...]
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer ();
    }
    [...]
    public function send() {
        [...]

        $this->mail->MsgHTML = $body; // or MsgBody?

        $this->mail->Send ();
        // return $this->mail_object->send ( $this->email_to, $headers, $body );
    }
}
```

You can also pass the `PHPMailer` instance to the constructor of your class.

Comment: Note that you should wrap the `$this->mail->Send()` call with the `try/catch` block, rather than the definition of the class. I did not tried to fix such issues, only to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that right after I posted the question. Funny how that happens after staring at it for 30 minutes.  PS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer ();
```

was out of scope because it was defined outside of the mailer class.
causing an empty class for $mail to be created.

Comment: "causing an empty class for $mail to be created.": no, I think you misunderstood the response. An instance of `PHPMailer` is present in the variable `$mail` but due to how variables are scoped in PHP, no variable called `$mail` exists in the scope of the method `mailer::send`.

Answer (score -1):

Your class should not be declared inside the try-catch method. Consider an

```
include_once 'pathToMailerClass';
```

Comment: That's not right, the issue comes from the fact `$mail` does not exists in the scope of the class, since it's declared outside.

Comment: This is right but... I maintain my comment about removing that junk